# Can't change opacity (alpha) programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uikit

Created a button on my storyboard and created an outlet for it in my view controller

```
property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonGetStarted;
```

But for the life of me, I cannot change its opacity from the code (in the **viewDidLoad** or **viewDidAppear** call) with things like:

```
_buttonGetStarted.alpha = 0.5f;
```

or

```
self.buttonGetStarted.alpha = 0.5f;
```

Only changing the alpha from the properties of the button in storyboard works.

why is that?

Comment: Are you sure that the outlet is connected?

Comment: Yeah, odds are that `buttonGetStarted` is nil, because it's not properly connected in the XIB.

Comment: Jack Wu -- that was the problem. I didn't notice it, but the outlet connection was somehow deleted. I guess I did that by mistake and did not notice it. If you write this in an answer, I'll be able to credit your Stackoverflow account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:
1) Check to make sure you didn't subclass your button in the Storyboard.

2) Sometimes I find using the method call helps.

```
[self.buttonGetStarted setAlpha:0.5f];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The dot and square bracket syntax are equivalent.

Comment: @thelaws You're right, but I feel like I've run into this issue before and switching to bracket syntax resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are executing the code on the main thread